# How to add prefix and suffix to dictionary value which is not None

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and inside this dictionary have some values as lists. And some values are none. I want to add prefix and suffix for these key values which are valid list items. And keep blank in None values. How can I do this?

```
dict = {
1: ['Item A1', 'Item A2', 'Item A3'],
2: ['Item B1'],
3: '',
4: ['Item C1', 'Item C2', 'Item C3'],
5: '',
6: ['Item D1', 'Item D2']
}

prfix_p = '<p>'
suffix_p = '</p>'
```

I want to achieve something like this

```
<p>Item A1</p>
<p>Item A2</p>
<p>Item A3</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), and provide a [mre]. "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site because SO isn't a free online coding service. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`""` is not None. it's an empty string. You can do something like:

```py
dict_ = {
    1: ['Item A1', 'Item A2', 'Item A3'],
    2: ['Item B1'],
    3: '',
    4: ['Item C1', 'Item C2', 'Item C3'],
    5: '',
    6: ['Item D1', 'Item D2']
}

prefix_p = '<p>'
suffix_p = '</p>'

for k, v in dict_.items():
    if v:
        dict_[k] = [prefix_p + item + suffix_p for item in v]
```

Then when you print the dictionary's item :

```py
for k, v in dict_.items():
    print(k, v)
```

output:

```
1 ['<p>Item A1</p>', '<p>Item A2</p>', '<p>Item A3</p>']
2 ['<p>Item B1</p>']
3 
4 ['<p>Item C1</p>', '<p>Item C2</p>', '<p>Item C3</p>']
5 
6 ['<p>Item D1</p>', '<p>Item D2</p>']
```

* <sub>Note: do not use built-in names(`dict`) as you variable names.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to print the results? If so, it's pretty simple:

```
for item in d.values():
    if item:
        for value in item:
            print(f"{prfix_p}{value}{suffix_p}")
```

Output:

```
<p>Item A1</p>
<p>Item A2</p>
<p>Item A3</p>
<p>Item B1</p>
<p>Item C1</p>
<p>Item C2</p>
<p>Item C3</p>
<p>Item D1</p>
<p>Item D2</p>
```